# In toc, two chapters appear on the same line when the chapter does not have any section

Tags: table-of-contents

I have report type document for my thesis. When the chapters do not have sections, the next chapter appears on the same line in toc.

[image]

[image]

Please let me know what to add more for code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%%---- continued ----

\titlecontents*{chapter}% <section-type>
[0pt]% <left>
{\addvspace{1em}}% <above-code>
{\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\input{thesis-statement/statement}
\ifoddchapterpage
\newoddpage
\fi

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\input{introduction/introduction}
\ifoddchapterpage
\newoddpage
\fi
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full (yet minimal) compilable code, reproducing the problem, that we can play with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`titletoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (section **6.2 And more**):

> This starred version groups the entries in a single paragraph.

So, use `\titlecontents`, not `\titlecontents*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\addvspace{1em}}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Thesis Statement}\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Introduction}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Research approach}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Research methodology}\lipsum[21-30]
\section{Contributions}\lipsum[31-40]

\chapter{Another chapter}\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Final chapter}\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works well. Thank you so much, Werner.