# The name at the beginning of the letters in the appendix does not change in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titletoc, nameref

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\textit{Division}}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{\textit{Addition}}

\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\addvspace{1em}}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

% Does not work VVVVV
\titlecontents{appendix}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\addvspace{1em}}% <above-code>
  {\bfseries\appendixname\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
  % Does not work ΛΛΛΛΛ

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Thesis Statement}\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Introduction}\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Another chapter}\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Final chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I added a picture below and I want the part that says ***Division*** to write ***Addition***.

[image]

Related to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414239/33075

Comment: Not *Addendum*?

Comment: It may be _**Addendum**_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could patch the `appendices` environment to change the chapter prefix in TOC for the appendix entries.

One possibility:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\textit{Division}}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{\textit{Addition}}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0pt]
  {\addvspace{1em}}
  {\bfseries\chapapp\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <- changed
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}

\newcommand*\chapapp{\chaptername}% <- added

\usepackage{etoolbox}% <- added
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}
  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\def\protect\chapapp{\protect\appendixname}}}% <- added
\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}
  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\def\protect\chapapp{\protect\chaptername}}}% <- added

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Thesis Statement}\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Introduction}\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Another chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Final chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]